# How can I create a program in VBScript that used a keystroke command to transfer data to a folder?

Tags: object, vbscript

How can I, in VBScript create this program? I have the code to transfer the data:`' Create a Folder

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\FSO")
```

`

I want to be able to choose a piece of text (That I haven't downloaded) and used a keystroke command to send it to a folder. How do I create the keystroke command? Do I have to make new variables to store the text or can I keep using `objFSO`? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear ?,please explain in detail ,First you have to create one file ,then only you should allow to select the piece of text from that file

Comment: When I say user, I am referring to myself. What do you mean when you say i have to create one file, can I not have information that I haven't downloaded and use a keystroke shortcut or command to send said information (text) to a file?